# Are there any alternatives of Tanos (Festool) T-Loc systainers

Tags: tool-identification

Gone through [the catalogue](https://www.festool.de/produkte/systainer,-sortainer-und-systainer-port) of Festool systainers and I see a really big number of surprising options and approaches. It sounds like it's worth on investing into them to have everything unified. Though not yet sure of alternatives.

What are the better alternatives of Tanos (Festool) T-Loc systainers?

Comment: This is currently framed as a product recommendation or opinion, which is out of scope for this site. That said, many tool sellers and woodworking catalogs do sell several competing storage container systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on what it takes for it to be 'better' for you.  There are several major players with similar product lines.  Here are some of the big players in stacking tool boxes.

**Tanos Systainer**
Offered in a variety of configurations, with different heights (Sys I - SYS V) and different footprints (Standard, Midi, and Maxi).  Also offer versions with drawers.  Probably the most complete system, but also the most expensive.  The container seals are not waterproof.  Used by several different vendors including Festool (white and green), Veritas (black and gold), and Makita (first generation, blue).

**Dewalt T-Stak**
Less expensive than Tanos and with fewer, but still many, configurations.  The containers seals are not waterproof. [Link](http://www.dewalt.com/en-us/products/gear-and-equipment/tool-storage/tstak-ii--flat-top/dwst17807)

**Bosch L-Boxx**
Similar to Dewalt's T-Stak.   A few more options including a variety of part container sizes for the locking parts containers. [Link](http://www.boschtools.com/us/en/boschtools-ocs/tool-and-accessory-storage-23539-c/)

**DeWalt ToughSystem**
Not nearly as complete of storage system as the Tanos or T-Stak, but much heavier duty.  These are very durable and have waterproof seals. Available in the US at Home Depot stores. [Link](http://www.dewalt.com/products/gear-and-equipment/tool-storage/tough-system)

**Ridgid Tool Storage**
These are similar to the Dewalt ToughSystem boxes.  Only three enclosed plus an open top boxes are available.  The enclosed boxes have waterproof seals and are all very durable.  Available in the US at Home Depot stores [Link](https://www.ridgid.eu/nl/en/professional-tool-storage-system)

**Milwaukee Packout**
This is the new kid on the block.  Just released in the fall of 2017, they offer a variety of toolboxes, parts containers, and open topped totes that interlock together.  Milwaukee has said they plan on expanding their offerings in this product line, but it is still fairly new.  [Link](https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Storage-Solutions/PACKOUT)